# Substitute first X occurrences

Tags: google-sheets

I can replace all occurrences

```
=SUBSTITUTE("a_b_c_d", "_", "")
```

to get the string "abcd". Or I can replace the 1st occurrence

```
=SUBSTITUTE("a_b_c_d", "_", "", 1)
```

to get the string "ab_c_d". But how can I replace the first X occurrences? I don't know a way to recursively call a function. and `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("a_b_c_d", "_", "", 1), "_", "", 1)` is not really an acceptable answer because it would always just replace the first 2 occurrences but what if I need to replace 2 or 3 or 4 or X occurrences, but not all occurrences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(,SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","_",3),""),{"_",""},"")))
```

- SUBSTITUTE the 3rd occurrence of `_` with a skull
- SPLIT the given string by the skull
- Globally SUBSTITUTE only the first part of splitted string with ""
- JOIN them back

---

<sub>Legend:</sub>
<sub>=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(,SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(❹,"❶","❶",❷),""),{"❶",""},"❸")))</sub>

<sub>❶search_for</sub>
<sub>❷Number of occurrences to be replaced</sub>
<sub>❸replace_with</sub>
<sub>❹text_to_search</sub>

Comment: That would only keep the 3rd `_`. If there are 4 or more `_` it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Nick I think it would. You need to change 3 to 4. Have you tested it?  If so, provide me a Example string and desired output?

Comment: It looks very nice to me

Comment: Oddly, if you ask this to replace more occurrences than there are, it doesn't error but returns some garbled concatenation. e.g. abcda_b_c_d

Comment: Yes because the inner substitute would do nothing and the split would do nothing, then the outer substitute replacing "\_"  with the {"","_"} array would give the original string less underlines followed by the original string.

Comment: Also as an afterthought you can replace the first n occurrences with another character instead of deleting them e.g. =ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(,SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\_","\_☠",3),"☠"),"\_",{"|","_"})))

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=regexreplace(REGEXEXTRACT(A2, rept("[^_]*_", 2)), "_", text(,))&mid(A2, len(REGEXEXTRACT(A2, rept("[^_]*_", 2)))+1, len(A2))
```

The **2** the the REPT function that repeats the pattern is the indicator or how many to replace. (in two places)

[Linked spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11vM7YzJ7NL-o-woWevXKYSiOAhG3dAYMUyq1pogfKT0/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]